# Simple password protection for google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm developing an application and I want to use Google App Engine for simple test and development purposes.

I want to deploy the app but others can't see it without the right password. How should I include a simple password (the post request and HTML forms etc., are already in place) for this project? Should I include it in the app.yaml file or something? Should I hash it? I don't want to use a database.

It needs to be really simple but secure enough for our purposes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to depend on which language you are using, given that the question has been tagged with python, then I would assume that the simplest and most vulnerable password protection should suffice. Like so:

```
class SimplestPassword(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        # HTML: <input name="password" type="text" />
        if self.request.get('password') == 'this_passsword':
            self.response.write('The password is: this_password')
        else:
            self.response.write('The password is not: {}'.format(str(self.request.get('password')))
```

You will then need to update the yaml endpoint to use the new handler.

For something that might be more secure possibly this:

- http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/webapp2_extras/security.html?highlight=password
- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/authenticating-users-firebase-appengine

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm going to go for something like this.